# Reading netCDF in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, netcdf

I'd like to work on netCDF data from two website : ISIMIP and earthstat. You can have an example of data on http://www.earthstat.org/data-download/ (harvested area and yield for 175 crops) and https://esg.pik-potsdam.de/search/isimip/. 
The idea is to match these data with an other layer on ArcMap (joint to a shapefile for example).

I know netCDF files are to big but I just need to extract one layer from these files. I mean I need an array with all latitude and longitude but for data from earthstat I only need the production layer and for data from ISIMIP (with a time dimension) I only need an array for one year for example.

How can I extract the data I want from these netCDF files and convert it in csv or txt file to read it with ArcMap 10.5.1?

Comment: This can be done with `R`. See the `NetCDF` part from this class [R for Earth-System Science](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/index.html)

Comment: I followed guidelines of Tung's link and it worked for what I needed to do.